# How to use processor 'GetFile' in Apache NIFI to get the file of network-attached disks

Tags: apache-nifi

I just start using Apache NIFI,what i want to do is using the processor 'GetFile' to get some file from a remoting network-attached machine to my local disks,but i don't know how to configure it in the settings of the processor,and i can not find any documents about this question, Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The GetFile processor does not support remote locations, the appropriate solution is to use ListFile + FetchFile rather than GetFile.

Answer (score 4):

There is extensive documentation on the [Apache NiFi website](https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html) and within your running instance of NiFi, you can right-click on any processor and select "Usage" to see this documentation inline.

To configure any processor, right-click and select "Configuration", then switch to the "Properties" tab. In [`GetFile`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GetFile/index.html), you need to provide the path to the directory you want to monitor as the `Input Directory` property, and the file name or pattern you want to retrieve as the `File Filter`. If this is a specific file known a priori, you can provide a literal name. If it is a pattern (i.e. all CSV files), you can use a pattern like `[^\.].*\.csv`. You should use the same input path as you would use to browse to the files on the host operating system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But after i read the extensive  document ,I know how to configure the getfile processor to monitor a directory of my local disk,but  i still don't know how to monitor a directory of remoting network-attached machine instead of a local disk.Can you show me how to configure this?For example,the ip of my computer is 192.168.1.101,but i want to monitor a directory of another machine that its ip is 192.168.1.110.Thanks

Comment: As Bryan mentioned above, if you cannot access the files via the operating system, `GetFile` will not be the correct processor to use.